# how to count number of rows in csv file using php?

Tags: php, csv

I make a php page in which i populate csv file to the checkbox,how i count number of rows of csv file.

Here is my code:

```
$file = $fu['filepath'].$fu['filename'];
        $handle=@fopen($file,"r");
        if($handle) {
            while($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024)){
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='receptionts[]' checked='checked' value='".$row[0].'|'.$row[1] ."' /> ".$row[0]." <br />";
                }
        } 
        else {
            // File doesn't exist. do something.
        }
```

Comment: how can i get total number of rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$file = $fu['filepath'].$fu['filename'];
$fileData=@file($file,"r");
$noOfLines = count($fileData);        

if ($noOfLines > 0) {
    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024)) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='receptionts[]' checked='checked' value='".$row[0].'|'.$row[1] ."' /> ".$row[0]." <br />";
    }
} else {
  // File doesn't exist. do something.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: its return 1 but my csv file contain 5 rows

Comment: yeah, sorry. the call to file was wrong. try this **@file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);**

Comment: then how to count total number of rows?

Comment: please check my edited comment. :) I'm not really used to these comment boxes

Comment: Welcome, Arif. One more thing I just noticed looking at the code, you'll have to change the $row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024) with something like $row = array_shift($fileData) because you already read the file into memory.

Comment: when i upload no file it gives result 1 but i want result zero

Comment: Try adding $fileData = array(); before reading the file. Or you can check if the variable is set before using count().